# How to separate only the IP Addresses?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

How can I separate only the IP addresses from the pic below?
[image: kali screenshot]

Comment: how much do you know about `grep` ?

Comment: the text could be easily extracted with any free online OCR service.

Comment: Please use the code tag to display output like this instead of posting an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pipe it through `egrep`: `... | grep -E '^[.0-9]+$'`
will discard all lines which have anything else than dots and digits 0-9.
(Yes, one could elaborate a more restrictive pattern, but the above is simple to remember and fast to type. Actually I'd even use `egrep` instead of `grep -E` but that is depreciated according to `(e)grep --help`.)

Comment: Thanks but hey If I wanted the other way around, I mean If I wanted to leave the strings and filter IP addresses?

Comment: Just use `grep -vE` : `-v` = `--invert-match` selects non-matching lines. (RTFM - _i.e.,_ see `grep --help` for further info! ;-))

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' access_log
```

`-o`: Only matching string/int

`-E`: Extended regex, will force `grep` to behave more like `egrep`